# How to use query params in cases where we need to construct the query manually?

Tags: python, sql

I'm using Python 2 and have the following code:

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    info("Updating {} records".format(len(records_to_update)))
    for record in records_to_update:
        query = "UPDATE my_table SET "
        params_setters = []
        # Process all fields except wsid when updating
        for index, header in enumerate(DB_COLUMNS_IN_ORDER[1:]):
            if record[index] is not None:
                params_setters.append("{} = '{}' ".format(header, record[index]))
        query += " , ".join(params_setters)
        query += " WHERE id = '{}'".format(record[0])
        cursor.execute(query)
```

How can I use query params for escaping here and not have to do it manually in places like:

```
params_setters.append("{} = '{}' ".format(header, record[index]))
```

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: @Talon Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to use a prepared statement. If you are using a driver where `%s` is used to represent a query parameter (SQLite uses `?`), then:

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    info("Updating {} records".format(len(records_to_update)))
    params = []
    for record in records_to_update:
        query = "UPDATE my_table SET "
        params_setters = []
        # Process all fields except wsid when updating
        for index, header in enumerate(DB_COLUMNS_IN_ORDER[1:]):
            if record[index] is not None:
                params_setters.append("{} = %s ".format(header))
                params.append(record[index])
        query += " , ".join(params_setters)
        query += " WHERE id = %s"
        params.append(record[0])
        cursor.execute(query, params)
```